# Is it possible to create an android app which can cast device screen including "negative colors" accessibility feature instead of true colors?

Tags: android, google-cast

I have low vision and use the "negative colors" accessibility feature of android on my devices. I got a Google Chromecast to cast my screen to my TV, but the streaming is in true colors, not the negative colors, no matter what application I use.

Is it possible to create an android app which can cast device screen including "negative colors" accessibility feature instead of true colors? Or is it technically impossible?

Answer (score 0):

By "Negative Colors", are you referring to "Color Inversion" or is it something else? Apps don't have control over mirroring/cast screening; it is done at the framework level. If that is not honored by mirroring, then please file a bug.

Comment: Naddaf, thank you very much for your answer! It is exactly what I needed to know. I will file a bug.